# How can I convert Python file with data files more than one to .exe format?

Tags: python, py2exe, setup.py

I am new and Python and programming. I tried to write code which needs one .docx, one .xlsx and one image file to work correctly. When convert it to .exe format with py2exe, something went wrong and my program didn't open! I just changed setup.py file as follows:

```
import os
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sys
import os
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH

Mydata_files = [('Data.docx', ['C:/Users/Murat/Desktop/Combobox/Data.docx']),
                   ('Data.xlsx', ['C:/Users/Murat/Desktop/Combobox/Data.xlsx']),
                   ('Logo.gif', ['C:/Users/Murat/Desktop/Combobox/Logo.gif'])]

setup(console=['Combobox.py'],
      data_files = Mydata_files,
      options={"py2exe":{"includes": ["lxml._elementpath"], "unbuffered": True, "optimize": 2}})
```

Now, I can see my data files in the dist folder but my code raises permission error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Combobox.py", line 94, in <module>
  File "pandas\util\_decorators.pyc", line 299, in wrapper
  File "pandas\io\excel\_base.pyc", line 336, in read_excel
  File "pandas\io\excel\_base.pyc", line 1057, in _init_
  File "pandas\io\excel\_base.pyc", line 938, in inspect_excel_format
  File "pandas\io\common.pyc", line 651, in get_handle
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Data.xlsx
```

The line about the Data.xlsx file in my code is as follows:

```
df=pd.read_excel("Data.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thank you, EldinAyal! You are right, it was my mistake but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is use an input() command at the end to wait for the user before closing the console

Also please always use **main** when writting scripts to  not run into weird behavior when importing

```
if __name__ == '__main__': #Use dunder method as a best practice

Mydata_files = []
for files in os.listdir("C:/Users/Murat/Desktop/Combobox/"):
    f1 = "C:/Users/Murat/Desktop/Combobox/" + files
    if os.path.isfile(f1):
        f2 = 'images', [f1]
        Mydata_files.append(f2)

setup(
    console=['trypyglet.py.py'],
    data_files=Mydata_files,
    options={
        "py2exe": {
            "unbuffered": True,
            "optimize": 2
        }
    }
)
input = input() # Use input to wait for the user
```

Comment: Thank you, Sys.Overdrive! After correcting my mistake ("trypyglet.py.py" must be "Combobox.py"), I tried your suggestions but still gives this error:
KeyError: 'lxml.etree'

Comment: Are you sure you installed lxml.etree correctly ? [link](https://lxml.de/3.7/installation.html)